# getting max data in multiple join

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, max

i have the data like this

purchase_order (po)

```
po_id   pi_id    store
112     789      ABC
113     101      DEF
114     102      GHI
115     103      JKL
```

purchase_items (pi)

```
pi_id  barcode   price    date
789    123       500      2020-06-04
101    123       400      2020-06-03
102    456       500      2020-06-02
103    456       400      2020-06-01
```

product

```
barcode   product
123       milk
456       tea
```

I want to get the latest price for each barcode if the store exclude "GHI"

expected result

```
barcode  price
123      500
456      400
```

how should i do ?

Answer (score 1):

One option uses a correlated subquery:

```
select
    p.barcode,
    (
        select pi.price
        from purchase_items pi
        inner join purchase_orders po on po.pi_id = pi.pi_id
        where pi.barcode = p.barcode and po.store <> 'GHI'
        order by pi.date desc limit 1
    ) price
from product p
```

Answer (score 1):

`row_number()` is one method:

```
select pi.barcode, pi.price
from (select pi.*, row_number() over (partition by pi.barcode order by pi.date desc) as seqnum
      from purchase_items pi
      where not exists (select 1
                        from purchase_orders po 
                        where po.pi_id = pi.pi_id and po.store = 'GHI'
                       )
     ) pi
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use join with max-function:

```
select pi.barcode, max(pi.price)
from purchase_items pi
  join purchase_order po on po.pi_id=pi.pi_id
where po.store!='GHI'
group by pi.barcode
```

Answer (score 0):

A way of using subqueries.

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT
    a.`barcode`,
    a.`price` 
FROM
    purchase_items a 
WHERE a.`date` = 
    (SELECT 
        MAX(`date`) 
    FROM
        purchase_items i 
    WHERE i.barcode = a.barcode 
        AND 'GHI' != 
        (SELECT 
            store 
        FROM
            purchase_order 
        WHERE pi_id = i.`pi_id` 
        LIMIT 1)) ;
```